# Try/Catch block issue

Tags: java, android, exception

I know this question may sound silly, but it happened. I put some statements in catch to handle the exception(that it should go to some screen) and it always used to go in that catch block. So I removed the try/catch so that my app crashes so that I could identify the exception. But, interestingly, it didn't crash. Is it possible?

Comment: We can't possibly answer this unless you show us the code in question.

Comment: Is it possible that the function that used to contain the try/catch is itself wrapped in a try/catch?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You just experienced it. Post code quickly before the downvoting begins!

Comment: Is it possible? -- No. Post you code so that i can clarify my answer.

Comment: If you are trying for example catch Runtime exception, which is not meant to be cought, you will get warning based on trying this, and if your code is ok, then without this it will run correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. See if your method has a "throws XXXException" declaration. if true, that means the caller  (or caller's caller .... ) has catched the exception and handled it there.
2. If the method didn't declare any exceptions to throw, that means the "exception" you catched is a "RuntimeException", which could be thrown without declaration.

That's the 2 scenarios where you won't get an app crash.

Comment: I think second scenario sounds good..

Comment: What is runtimeException here..? All the ecxeptions occur at runtime, right?